# "reputation: top x% overall" appears on meta, not on SO?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [top - user x% reputation missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124226/top-user-x-reputation-missing)

I see it on my meta profile (next to the reputation tag), and don't see it on my SO profile.

Which one is correct?  Which one represents the future?

(I'm marking as a bug that the two sites are not consistent, not that it does or does not exist. I kind of like it, FWIW.)

Comment: Yes, the `leagueRank` `<div>` appears to be empty on SO, but contain the expected link on Meta. Probably just an oversight in the revamping of the reputation system.

Comment: We had a small window where our network-level rep aggregation cache was out-of-date, but it's fixed now.