# top - user x% reputation missing

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, top-users

I've noticed that from this morning on all of my user' profile pages on Stack Exchange accounts the indication of top% of user reputation has disappeared.

(as you can see in figure pointed put by red arrow number 1)

Is this due to the recalculations of reputation that are been done, as explained by the message that appeared in all pages of Stack Exchange sites?

(as you can see in figure pointed put by red arrow number 2)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**  Emmett has run the backfills, and the links are back on.

This is also related to the SE.com data needing a backfill after the global recalcs (but hey, it's the last time this will happen).

The links are disabled for the moment because they'll just result in errors...we'll enable them as soon as the backfill is complete (hopefully later today).