# "top X% this X" gone?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

["reputation: top x% overall" appears on meta, not on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124193/reputation-top-x-overall-appears-on-meta-not-on-so)

This shows you your percentage among users.

```
top % this year
top % this month
top % this week
```

This problem is back, sorry if I am not "doing it right".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was an issue with performance on SE.com early this morning which ultimately turned out to be a mis-monitored and downed app pool on one of our web servers.  In debugging that we disabled the top links to stop the error flow...and I forgot to turn it back on.  Sorry! It's re-enabled now.